# Vim: How to set automatic indent (using equal sign) to 4 spaces?

Tags: vim

When I use equal sign to indent text in vim, it indents it with 3 spaces.. I need 4. 
The code I've tried to change it in `.vimrc` file (inspired by some example I've found, but it does not work):

```
autocmd BufWinLeave *.* mkview
autocmd BufWinEnter *.* silent loadview
set smartindent
set tabstop=4       " The width of a TAB is set to 4.
                    " Still it is a \t. It is just that
                    " Vim will interpret it to be having
                    " a width of 4.

set shiftwidth=4    " Indents will have a width of 4

set softtabstop=4   " Sets the number of columns for a TAB

set expandtab       " Expand TABs to spaces
```

Do you know how to change automatic indent (by using equal sign) to 4 spaces? Really appreciate any help

Comment: In many files, thu indent of one line depends on the lines above. Can you give some example text and a filetype?

Comment: Don't put indent settings in your `~/.vimrc` file. They are buffer local settings and should be applied to each buffer usually by filetype. Instead put your indent setting in like so `setlocal tabstop=4` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

`=` doesn't trigger smart indent, it triggers the `equalprg` or, if not configured, `lisp`, `cindent`, or `indentexpr`. To use smart indent, use `>` and `<` (as in: `>>` to indent the current line, `<<` to outdent the current line, `>2j` to indent the current line and two below it, etc.). Of course, you could remap it if you like...

Your main options for smartindent are correct (`shiftwidth`, `tabstop`). Your comment on `tabstop` says tabs are retained, but you've changed that by setting `expandtab` later.